# Why is my derived class showing as abstract?

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, abstract-class, pure-virtual

Getting an error that says

> ..\src\CS20 Lab 2 Part 2.cpp:75:38: error: invalid new-expression of abstract class type 'CS_Student'

Base Class:

```
    /*
 * Student.h
 *
 *  Created on: Jan 23, 2020
 *      Author: Student
 */

    enter code here

#ifndef STUDENT_H_`#define STUDENT_H_
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Student {
protected:
    string *name;
    int *age;
public:
    Student();

    void setName(string s) ;
    void setAge(int i);
    string getName() const;
    int getAge() const;
    virtual void print() = 0;

    virtual ~Student();

};
#endif /* STUDENT_H_ */
```

Student.cpp:

```
/*
 * Student.h
 *
 *  Created on: Jan 23, 2020
 *      Author: Student
 */

#ifndef STUDENT_H_
#define STUDENT_H_
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Student {
protected:
    string *name;
    int *age;
public:
    Student();

    void setName(string s) ;
    void setAge(int i);
    string getName() const;
    int getAge() const;
    virtual void print() = 0;

    virtual ~Student();

};

#endif /* STUDENT_H_ */
```

Derived Class:

```
/*
 * CSStudent.cpp
 *
 *  Created on: Jan 23, 2020
 *      Author: Student
 */

#include <string>
#include <iostream>

#include "CS_Student.h"
#include "Student.h"
using namespace std;

CS_Student::CS_Student() {
    favProgLang = new string;
    cout << "CS_Student object created!" << endl;

}
void CS_Student::setFavProgLang(string s){
    *favProgLang = s;
}
string CS_Student::getFavProgLang() const{
    return *favProgLang;
}
void CS_Student::print() const{
    cout << "\nPRINT REPORT FOR CS_STUDENT OBJECT" << endl;
    cout << "\tName: " << *name << endl;
    cout << "\tAge: " << *age << endl;
    cout << "\tFavorite Programming Language: " << *favProgLang << endl;
}
CS_Student::~CS_Student() {
    delete favProgLang;
    cout << "CS_Student object destroyed!" << endl;
}

/*
    void setFavProgLang(string s);
    string getFavProgLang() const;
    void print() const;
 */
```

Derived header:

```
/*
 * CSStudent.h
 *
 *  Created on: Jan 23, 2020
 *      Author: Student
 */

#ifndef CS_STUDENT_H_
#define CS_STUDENT_H_

#include <string>
#include "Student.h"

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


class CS_Student: public Student {
private:
    string *favProgLang;
public:
    CS_Student();

    void setFavProgLang(string s);
    string getFavProgLang() const;
    void print() const;

    virtual ~CS_Student();
};

#endif /* CS_STUDENT_H_ */
```

Main:

```
#include "CS_Student.h"
#include "EnglishStudent.h"

/*******************************************************************************
* Function Prototypes
*******************************************************************************/
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void getInput(CS_Student**, const int);
void getInput(EnglishStudent**, const int);
void display(Student*);

/*******************************************************************************
* int main()
*   Starting point of the program.
*
* Output:
*   An integer to signal to the OS the exit code.
*******************************************************************************/

int main() {
    // variables
    const int CS_SIZE = 2;
    const int ENG_SIZE = 3;
    CS_Student* csArray[CS_SIZE];
    EnglishStudent* engArray[ENG_SIZE];

    // call the getInput method overloads for both arrays
    getInput(csArray, CS_SIZE);
    getInput(engArray, ENG_SIZE);

    // call the polymorphic display function for both arrays
    for (int i = 0; i < CS_SIZE; i++) {
        display(csArray[i]);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < ENG_SIZE; i++) {
        display(engArray[i]);
    }

    // release the dynamic memory for objects inside both arrays
    for (int i = 0; i < CS_SIZE; i++) {
        delete csArray[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < ENG_SIZE; i++) {
        delete engArray[i];
    }

    // terminate
    return 0;
}

/*******************************************************************************
* void getInput(CS_Student** objArray, const int SIZE)
*   Use a for loop to create dynamic CS student objects. Prompt the user for the
*   name/age/favorite programming language of each CS student. Store the
*   information in the dynamic object.
*
* Inputs:
*   objArray - a double-pointer that should be treated as an array of dynamic
*              CS student objects
*   SIZE     - a constant integer that represents the size of the array
*******************************************************************************/

void getInput(CS_Student** objArray, const int SIZE) {
    // variables
    string name = "", fpl = "";
    int age = 0;

    // for each CS student
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        // create the dynamic CS student object
        objArray[i] = new CS_Student();

        // prompt and store the name of the current CS student
        cout << "Enter the name for CS student #" << i + 1 << ": ";
        getline(cin, name);

        // prompt and store for the age of the current CS student
        cout << "Enter the age for CS student #" << i + 1 << ": ";
        cin >> age;

        // need to ignore the newline in the buffer
        cin.ignore();

        // prompt and store the favorite programming language of the current
        // CS student
        cout << "Enter the favorite programming language for CS student #"
             << i + 1 << ": ";
        getline(cin, fpl);

        // add the data to the dynamic object
        objArray[i]->setName(name);
        objArray[i]->setAge(age);
        objArray[i]->setFavProgLang(fpl);
    }
}

/*******************************************************************************
* void getInput(EnglishStudent** objArray, const int SIZE)
*   Use a for loop to create dynamic English student objects. Prompt the user
*   for the name/age/favorite book of each English student. Store the
*   information in the dynamic object.
*
* Inputs:
*   objArray - a double-pointer that should be treated as an array of dynamic
*              English student objects
*   SIZE     - a constant integer that represents the size of the array
*******************************************************************************/

void getInput(EnglishStudent** objArray, const int SIZE) {
    // variables
    string name = "", book = "";
    int age = 0;

    // for each English student
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        // create the dynamic English student object
        objArray[i] = new EnglishStudent();

        // prompt and store the name of the current English student
        cout << "Enter the name for English student #" << i + 1 << ": ";
        getline(cin, name);

        // prompt and store for the age of the current English student
        cout << "Enter the age for English student #" << i + 1 << ": ";
        cin >> age;

        // need to ignore the newline in the buffer
        cin.ignore();

        // prompt and store the favorite book of the current English student
        cout << "Enter the favorite book for English student #"
             << i + 1 << ": ";
        getline(cin, book);

        // add the data to the dynamic object
        objArray[i]->setName(name);
        objArray[i]->setAge(age);
        objArray[i]->setFavBook(book);
    }
}

/*******************************************************************************
* void display(Student* obj)
*   A polymorphic function. Simply calls the (virtual) print method. Used to
*   demonstrate polymorphism. Any derived class that inherits from the Student
*   class can be used as an argument.
*
* Input:
*   obj - a pointer to an object that inherits from the Student class
*******************************************************************************/

void display(Student* obj) {
    obj->print();
}
```

Really confused because Student is my base class which has the pure virtual function
`virtual void print() = 0;`
and it's overridden in CS_Student
`void CS_Student::print() const`
I've also tried changing CS_Student here to Student and it doesn't change anything. Thanks in advance

Comment: Try using the `override` keyword on every declaration of a function that is supposed to override a function from a base class.

Comment: I see! I was missing the `const` from the base class. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Base: `virtual void print() = 0;`

Derived: `void print() const;`

That extra `const` in the derived version changes the signature of the derived function, the instance variable `this` is `const`, so that it doesn't match the base function. Either the base must be `const` or the derived must not be `const`. Prefer the former.

Eg.

```
virtual void print() = 0;
```

becomes

```
virtual void print() const= 0;
```

In C++ and more recent standard revisions you can catch this more easily by marking all functions you expect to override a base class function with the `override` keyword. This almost always results in a more easily understood error message.

Eg.

```
void print() const override;
```

results in (on my tool chain)

```
error: 'void CS_Student::print() const' marked 'override', but does not override
     void print() const override;
```